# ImportError while trying to use Web3.py

Tags: python, web3.py

I set up a private network on my computer and was running some codes written in Python using `web3.py`, until I faced **ImportError**:

> ImportError: The 'pyparsing' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.

This didn't happen in the beginning. I was running my codes and everything was running good, but today while playing around with `eth_tester` I faced this error, which looks more like common Python error. And from the time I first saw this error message I was unnable to run any of my codes, which were running normally before.

---

The error is invoked by this line:

```
import web3
```

---

I have these versions of modules in my PyCharm:

```
Pyparsing 2.2.0

Web3 3.11.1 

pip 9.0.1
```

---

- I am using WIN7SP1
- Codes are being launched from the Command-line interface
- I tried to reinstall `web3.py`, `pyparsing` and `eth_tester` in case problem was in module, but it didn't help

---

When I try `import pyparsing` it says:

> AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'

---

Yes, I was thinking to ask this question on StackOverflow, because I still think that this is more of Python problem, but this error happens only when I use web3.py and not any other module. So the problem might be in web3.

---

I appreciate any suggestions and comments on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure none of your other `.py` files are called `copy.py` or `pyparsing.py`. This sounds like an issue of mangle namespace.

Comment: `copy.py` was actually a problem in my case. Thank you @AdamY.